# CSS bug in new design - profile triangle

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There appears to be a small display bug with the "profile triangle" next to the user's name in the navigation bar.

[image: user links]

There's a random smudge to the left of the triangle that changes size and shape as you zoom the page in or out.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 7.  I have the page zoomed in a bit so it looks bigger than it does by default.

Comment: I confirm in Chrome. Nick can you add the browser you're using? Yours is bigger than mine.

Comment: Yup, info added.

Comment: Confirm in Firefox 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.